# Can we get URL of the left panel Admin menus clicked on the WordPress using hooks or filters or functions?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url, plugins

In a plugin development of WordPress, I need to find the URL of the left side panel Admin menus URL when they clicked, I have searched a lot for the hooks or filters which fired after the menus clicked but failed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The links in the menu are just hyperlinks, so they can be parsed in JS easily, if that’s what you mean. Otherwise, the current page is controlled by the path and query in the address bar which you can easily get to, too. Can you explain further what you need to do beyond what the [native menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) functions get you?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I want to mask those admin menus URLs, meaning When I click on the menus button the URL in the address bar should be different but the page should be of that menu clicked? Is that possible by using hooks or functions?

Comment: If you want things to be clicked without the URL changing you want event listeners. The event listener can cancel the link’s action although arguably the item should be a button instead of a link semantically. There’s no WordPress-specific things that should be needed.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for your help, I did understand. Also, I think if I mask the logged-in admin URL then those admin menu links also be masked.